# Codemagic IOS build fail flutter_udid

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, codemagic

I'm trying to build my flutter app with codemagic for IOS. As i dont have any mac computer.

But i'm facing an error on the build process.

```
Running pod install...                                             64.3s
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           126.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-05-03 21:14:57.055 xcodebuild[2494:21713] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-05-03 21:14:57.056 xcodebuild[2494:21713] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:30:9: fatal error: module 'flutter_udid' not found
    @import flutter_udid;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'SAMKeychain' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.4.99. (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
```

I have never developped anything on IOS yet. This configuration is untouched. I'm in Ubuntu dev environnement

And this is my codemagic default configration.

```
workflows:
  default-workflow:
    name: Default Workflow
    max_build_duration: 60
    environment:
      flutter: "v2.8.1"
      xcode: latest
      cocoapods: default
    scripts:
      - flutter packages pub get
      - find . -name "Podfile" -execdir pod install \;
      - flutter build ios --debug --no-codesign
    artifacts:
      - build/ios/ipa/*.ipa
      - /tmp/xcodebuild_logs/*.log
      - '*.snap'
      - build/windows/**/*.msix
      - flutter_drive.log
    publishing:
      email:
        recipients:
          - my@email.tld
```

We have to note that `find . -name "Podfile" -execdir pod install \;` also fails

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: /Users/builder/clone/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first.

 #  from /Users/builder/clone/ios/Podfile:17
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
 >      raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
 #    end
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

And this is my pdofile (it is not my file by the way)

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```